# What is 1950 Military Aircraft Blueprint to Aluminum Sheet Metal Process Called?

Tags: aircraft-manufacturer

I have sections of vintage aluminum sheetmetal with aircraft 'blueprints' stenciled, what is this process called?
One plane is identified as a F9 Cougar (plane outline shown), others have earlier font type that I believe are from F6 Hellcat production (sheetmetal was cut to square and used for custom picture frame backing of F6 photograph prints. Family worked from Grumman.

Regards

Comment: Welcome. "*what is this process called*" Which process are you talking about? Transferring a blueprint onto a metal sheet (commonly [silkscreen printing](https://www.pekoprecision.com/capabilities/metal-silk-screening/))?

Comment: Thanks, from what I've learned in researching, is the blueprints were transferred to aluminum sheets for use, similar to silk screening in the result, but believe there was a type of photographic process in the 40, 50s